# How to deploy WCF service to test server

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I have developed my first WCF and hosted it in IIS, and it is all working in my local box.  Can somebody please direct me to a paper or the Help that will show me how to deploy (step by step) this to my Test environment.

Thanks
BB

Comment: Right-click the project and choose Publish. Or what question are you asking?

Comment: Also on which version of iis you want it to be hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish to a test server the same way as you publish to the local server.

You just need to change the address that you are publishing to, and make sure that you are in the security context of a user that is allowed to publish to the test server.

However, I would advise you to create a setup project that you use to deploy your code, since you will also be able to use that to deploy to production.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FYI, link is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

Check here, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In most recent times we have used [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) with IIS6+

One set of directions in the form of step by step guide is the below link:

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/visual-studio2/Deploying-Services-with-Web-Deploy.aspx

It also works quite nicely with CI processes and has a lot functionality beyond just file copy.